# How to use filter with multiple criteria in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I'm working with Google Sheet for healthcare purposes organizing patients lists and endorsement to team issues:

```
=filter('CASES LIST'!C:R,('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="admission")+('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="pending")+('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="PCI"))
```

Can I make it shorter like:

```
=filter('CASES LIST'!C:R,('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="admission"or"pending"or"pci"))
```

I want to filter the data if it contains either `admission`, `pending` or `pci`.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following query formula (adjusting ranges to your needs), instead of the one you already use.

```
=QUERY({P1:R},"where Col2 matches 'admission|PCI|pending' ",0)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.